# Problems calling relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm getting problems calling relationships in laravel, I have 4 tables: users, tickets, stores, statuses. and I have a @OneToMany relationship in Users to Tickets (1 user have many tickets). the other relationships are @OneToOne (1 ticket have 1 store and status).

Now, I have 6 tickets in my table and 4 users, I can print the relationship to the 4 first tickets, but when I want to call the ticket 5 or 6, the relationship dissapears. 
The same thing with store and status, I can print the relationship while the id of the ticket is not greater than the number of items I have in my table.

these are my models:
User Model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasRoles;

    protected $fillable = [
        'id','name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function tickets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Ticket::class, 'usuario_id');
    }
}
```

Ticket Model:

```
class Ticket extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'comentarios', 'falla', 'modelo', 'no_serie', 'monto', 
'usuario_id', 'status_id', 'store_id'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id');
    }
    public function store()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Store::class, 'id');
    }
    public function status()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Status::class, 'id');
    }
}
```

Store Model:

```
class Store extends Model
{

    protected $table = "stores";
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'sucursal', 'dirección'
    ];

    public function ticket()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Ticket::class, 'store_id');
    }
}
```

Status Model:

```
    class Status extends Model
{

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = [
      'status'
    ];

    public function ticket()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Ticket::class, 'status_id');
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
$tickets = Ticket::all();



    return view('Admin.index', compact('tickets'));
```

View

```
@foreach($tickets as $ticket)
    <li>{{ $ticket->user }}</li>
@endforeach
```

result:

[Result of the foreach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnZNE.png)

In the view, I'm calling all the tickets ($tickets), and for each ticket, I print the relationship (user function). But in the result, you can see that just print first 4 relationships, (the number of my users), if I add 1 user, the relationship in the 5th ticket appears.
The Same problem with the other tables (store and status).

Answer (score 0):

Replace `user()` relationship in **Ticket** moedel to:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'usuario_id', 'id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in `Ticket model` you must change function to
`public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'usuario_id', 'id');
}`

or just `public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}`